# Inno Setup Service Log On As

Tags: configuration, windows-services, inno-setup, advapi32

Can you advice me how to get "Log On As" parameter of specific windows service?
I need to re-register service in our upgrade project and it needs to be run under the same account as it was set up originally.
I've found QueryServiceConfig in advapi32.dll with lpServiceStartName in returned structure but I am not able to make it work from Inno Setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use [`QueryServiceConfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from InnoSetup script. To use this function, you would have to allocate buffer from heap and that's impossible in InnoSetup. Instead you can use WMI, or to be more specific, the [`Win32_Service`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class, which contains the `StartName` property, that you've asked for. In InnoSetup script it might look like this:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
function GetServiceStartName(const AServiceName: string): string;
var
  WbemLocator: Variant;
  WbemServices: Variant;
  WbemObject: Variant;
  WbemObjectSet: Variant;  
begin;
  Result := '';
  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WbemServices := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2');
  WbemObjectSet := WbemServices.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Service ' +
    'WHERE Name = "' + AServiceName + '"');
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) and (WbemObjectSet.Count > 0) then
  begin        
    WbemObject := WbemObjectSet.Item('Win32_Service.Name="' + 
      AServiceName + '"');    
    if not VarIsNull(WbemObject) then
      Result := WbemObject.StartName;      
  end;
end;

procedure SvcStartNameTestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MsgBox(GetServiceStartName('Netlogon'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  SvcStartNameTestButton: TNewButton;
begin
  SvcStartNameTestButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  SvcStartNameTestButton.Parent := WizardForm;
  SvcStartNameTestButton.Left := 8;
  SvcStartNameTestButton.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight - 
    SvcStartNameTestButton.Height - 8;
  SvcStartNameTestButton.Width := 175;
  SvcStartNameTestButton.Caption := 'Get service start name...';
  SvcStartNameTestButton.OnClick := @SvcStartNameTestButtonClick;
end;
```

Quite easier (and probably faster) would be to make an external library and call it from the script. If you have Delphi or Lazarus, you can use the following function, which uses the [`QueryServiceConfig`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the [`lpServiceStartName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) member, that you asked for:

```
function GetServiceStartName(const AServiceName: string): string;
var
  BufferSize: DWORD;
  BytesNeeded: DWORD;
  ServiceHandle: SC_HANDLE;
  ServiceManager: SC_HANDLE;
  ServiceConfig: PQueryServiceConfig;
begin
  Result := '';
  ServiceManager := OpenSCManager(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  if ServiceManager <> 0 then
  try
    ServiceHandle := OpenService(ServiceManager, PChar(AServiceName),
      SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);
    if ServiceHandle <> 0 then
    try
      if not QueryServiceConfig(ServiceHandle, nil, 0, BufferSize) and
        (GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
      begin
        ServiceConfig := AllocMem(BufferSize);
        try
          if QueryServiceConfig(ServiceHandle, ServiceConfig, BufferSize,
            BytesNeeded)
          then
            Result := ServiceConfig^.lpServiceStartName;
        finally
          FreeMem(ServiceConfig);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      CloseServiceHandle(ServiceHandle);
    end;
  finally
    CloseServiceHandle(ServiceManager);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't liked the idea of linking external library so I finally solved the problem this way:

```
function GetServiceLogonAs():string;
var
  res : Integer;
  TmpFileName, FileContent: String;
begin
  TmpFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\Service_Info.txt';
  Exec('cmd.exe', '/C sc qc "MyServiceName" > "' + TmpFileName + '"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, res);
  if LoadStringFromFile(TmpFileName, FileContent)  then
  begin    
    Result := Trim(Copy(FileContent,Pos('SERVICE_START_NAME', FileContent)+20,Length(FileContent)-(Pos('SERVICE_START_NAME', FileContent)+21)));
    DeleteFile(TmpFileName);
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowErrorMsg('Error calling: GetServiceLogonAs(" + MYSERVICE + ")', res);
    Result := '';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's terrible solution. I'd rather follow the WMI way (see the first half of my post). That uses just Windows built-in COM interfaces.

Comment: What if WMI is not installed? There are still some clients that use WinXP. Anyway thank for your advice.

Comment: Why would you need to [`install it`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx#EMAA) ? Btw. guess what your code returns on my localized Czech Windows 7 ? There's no `SERVICE_START_NAME` tag, but I have [`Název_spouštěné_služby`](http://i.imgur.com/A5UXa.jpg) instead for the service start name tag.

Comment: OK, thank for you advice, I thought that WMI was not preinstalled on WinXP. By the way Název_spouštěné_služby seems inadequate translation because its not name of the service but name of the user account. ;-)